# Why is move_iterator::operator-> deprecated in C++20?

Tags: c++, deprecated, c++20

I read a [C++20 proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1252r2) that was adopted about this subject and the article said.

> The expression `(*iter).x` and the expression `iter->x` have the same semantics. For a `move_iterator`, `*iter` is an `xvalue`. `iter->x`, is an `lvalue`. Consequently, `(*iter).x` and `iter->x`  can produce **different behaviors**.

Is this exactly why it is deprecated in C ++ 20? Are there any other concepts and disadvantages that should not be used? Is there anyone who could explain it better with the code example,whats the best practice?

Comment: You should send some feedback to the author of the incorrect article.

Comment: Can you explain a little more which parts of the article are wrong?

Comment: Yes.  Please share a link to the article.

Comment: of course [article](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1252r2)

Comment: Ahh, so the article is explaining why they don't have the same semantics.  That is correct then.

Comment: Yes, the topic is explained in the article, but it would be more useful if someone explained it in more detail and more clearly.

Comment: @east1000: What is unclear about it?

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, just like you said, it is something that has already been deprecated and my curiosity does not change this fact, but when I learn a new information, it is my personal preference to learn that information from several different places.I wanted to hear the information of people who have detailed information on the subject here, perhaps because there is a possibility that there are deficiencies in the article. I asked this question maybe I would have a chance to get more detailed information.my regards.

Comment: @east1000: It's not an "article"; it's a proposal for the C++ standard. It is literally the paper that *caused* the functionality in question to be deprecated. There is no higher authority unless you were in the room while the paper was being discussed.

Comment: @NicolBolas I got it, thank you .